Switching between Spring profiles on different environments with the same WAR archive
When I try to build the application via Maven mvn install, it says
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'example_token' in value "${example_token}"
I assume it happens because the example_token does not exist in application.yml, it is both in application-dev.yml and application-prod.yml though.
The idea is to build one single WAR archive of the Maven application and switch the profiles according to the environment variables (SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev/SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod), for example. What is the best practice way to build a project via Maven to achieve this? One of the ways to solve this is to make mocked properties I suppose but I don't think it's a good approach.
I am thinking of linking Maven and Spring Boot profiles but still I am not sure how to properly create WAR archive because of the mentioned error.
I have two Spring Boot application profiles with three correspondent YAML files: application.yml, application-dev.yml and application-prod.yml. When I run the application locally from the Idea with, for instance, dev active profile, everything works great.
I am using Spring-boot 3.0.13 and Maven 3.9.5
UPD: Thankfully to @M.Deinum from the comments, I found the root of the issue: during the CI pipeline execution, it was needed to explicitly set "skip tests". The profile setting is required otherwise even if there are no tests in the app. If someone wants to do the same locally, I assume that mvn install -DskipTests would help

Set the active profile to dev while building. Or specify @ActiveProfile("dev") on the tests you have.

@M.Deinum thank you for the reply. Since Maven profiles are used if one wants to set a profile during build and Spring profiles are for a runtime, do you mean Spring profiles (runtime) will be the one that is used and the profile I set during build won't affect the running application anyhow? It's a bit unclear for me: if I set the active profile to dev during a build, will I be able to run a WAR file built with prod profile? In other words, will the WAR archive have the application-prod.yml file that it will be using?

Read, please read. I nowhere mention maven profiles, those have nothing to do with Spring profiles. I also nowhere said to hardcode it. The error you get is probably from a test that is being run, that test needs to be tied to a profile. Hence you need to add @ActiveProfiles("dev") to those tests. If not they will not run with profile dev (only in your IDE as you probably set an environment variable there).

@M.Deinum I don't have any tests in the application, the issue is that the component that have  @Value("${example_token}")   inside can't be created because of the Could not resolve placeholder 'example_token' in value "${example_token}" error. From your comment I see that you suggest to set the active profile to dev during build process, so I am not sure if the application will behave properly if I will use the artifact created with -Dspring.profiles.active=prod

If you don't have tests then the exception wouldn't occur. During build nothing is being instantiated just compiled and placed in a archive. So either you do have tests or do something really strange in your build. @Value will not be resolved during compilation only at startup. So yes during building you will need to set the profile to dev, this has zero effect on the actual artifact being created it will only be used for running tests.

@M.Deinum thanks a lot for the clear explanation.

Since you have already created different environment file. When you run your application, pass below profile information in vm arguments.
No need to change anything on application.yml file.
Eclipse-> Run as run configuration->In vm args section:
-Dspring.profile.active=dev

